# Returning http status code from Web Api controller in .Net core

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

How do I return Http Status code Like 500 and 404. Below is my code

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ImageController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public string Get(string date)
        {
            string result = string.Empty;
            var url = "https://myurl.com";
            var httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpRequest.GetResponse();
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();

            }
            return result;
        }

    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: change it to `public IActionResult Get(string date)`, then return `Ok(result);` or `return NotFound();` or `return StatusCode(500);`

Comment: What about 500 and 404?

Comment: `NotFound()` is 404. Or you could just do `return StatusCode(404);`. Same thing.

Comment: How do u add these codes in the exception block?

Comment: welcome to SO! if you hit right-click on `ControllerBase` and select 'Go To Definition', you should see the method `NotFound()` that @Andy spoke about. Dig around there a little to get an idea of what the base api controller provides.

Comment: `} catch (Exception ex){ return new StatusCode(500, ex); }` is a generic way to do that -- albeit you probably wouldn't want to do that in prod. maybe just use `ex.Message`.